# Why this bizarre output in c?

Tags: c

I have the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{

    char ch[10];

    gets(ch);

    printf("\nTyped: %s\n\n", ch);

    int i = 0;
    while ( ch[i] != '\0' )
    {
        printf("Letter: %c\n", ch[i]);
        i++;
    }

    printf("\nTyped: %s\n\n", ch);


}
```

and here is the output when i typed "Hello world is good"

```
hello world is good

Typed: hello world is good

Letter: h
Letter: e
Letter: l
Letter: l
Letter: o
Letter:
Letter: w
Letter: o
Letter: r
Letter: l
Letter:


Typed: hello worl♂
```

Why i am getting two different output for same command after while loop? does while loop has anything to do with it.. please help..

Comment: well, you have the cathedral on one hand, and the bizarre on the other :^)

Comment: Never use `gets`!  **Never!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your character array `ch` only has space for 10 chars. You typed something longer than 10 chars and tried to store it in that array, effectively writing beyond the end of the array into space that's not reserved for anything (or at least isn't reserved for your characters). You got lucky in this case and didn't write over anything important (your program didn't crash), but subsequent code comes along (the `printf()`, your `int i`, etc.) and changes that memory (it's the stack, after all, so it gets used in FIFO order).

Change your `char ch[10]` to `char ch[2048]` to give yourself a larger buffer to type into. You might also use `fgets()` instead of `gets()` so that you can limit the size of the input to your buffer size. If you use `gets()`, heed the warning on the man page:

> It is the caller's responsibility to ensure that the input line, if
>   any, is sufficiently short to fit in the string.

Answer (score 8):

You do know that "Hello world is good" is more than 10 bytes? The behavior in this case is **undefined**. Anything can happen, anything at all, from working as you *wanted* to total crash of your system with reformatting the hard-drive and burning junk over your ROM.

You must allocate enough space for `gets` to put the string in, and in this case you don't. That's the main reason why `gets` should be avoided, use `fgets` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you allocate only 10 characters (`char ch[10]`) which fits "hello worl". Afterwards there's only junk in memory you're trying to print.

Comment: but why it prints out fully when called immediately ... and not after the while loop?? this is my question... 10 byte is purposefully done to test this.. can u help now

Comment: @srisar - the behavior is **undefined**. Why? Because. Any answer will be a wrong one. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: probably because afterwards you allocate an integer which messes up the previously allocated char array.

Comment: downvoters are often cowards, an inevitable consequence of anonymous votes. I offset it.